# Installing of MapGuide?

Tags: installation, mapguide, mapguide-maestro

I installed mapguide open source 2.6 and mapguide maestro 6.3 on windows 7 !! the tutorial that i followed assure that on this version of mapguide you don't need to install any server web. now when i try to go to : localhost:8008/mapguide it gives me an error of connexion, and the same error when i try with maestro. I note that the adresse : localhost:8008 work and i have apache folder and php folder in the directory where i installed mapguide..it's an  error on mapguide server i guess.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the PHP version installed in your machine.

It says in [this article](https://mapguide.osgeo.org/faq_installandconfigure.html) that the version of PHP should be 5.3.8.

Also try to follow [these steps and notes](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/wiki/Release/2.6/Notes) and verify that your system meets the minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to start the services of the ApacheMapguide2.6 and Mapguide Server 2.6. If it already started, you just need to restart and try to go to localhost:8008/mapguide again. Everything will be fine I guess.